# how to make bundle for base name configuration.properties reachable?

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, executable-jar

i'm  using jboss6 to build a jar archive,
When I try to run my project, it gives the following exception massage

```
18:50:26,062 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name configuration-app, locale fr_FR

18:50:26,063 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)   at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
```

is there any solution to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `configuration-app_fr_FR.properties` file from your classpath.